# How to create a dictionary like variable or index for their keys to be used/matched later in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<a>
<b>
    <references>
        <reference>reference 1</reference>
        <reference>reference 2</reference>
        <reference>reference 3</reference>
    </references>
</b>
<c>
    <d>                     
        <p>
            Sample text 
            <page number="199" referenceAttribute="reference 2" /> Sample text 1
            <page number="17" referenceAttribute="reference 1" /> Sample text 2
            <page number="200" referenceAttribute="reference 2" /> Sample text 3
        </p>
    </d>
</c>
</a>
```

I need a xslt formula in order to display the text in the following format:

> Sample text [**199] Sample text 1 [*17] Sample text 2 [**200] Sample text 3

Basically I think I need some sort of index or dictionary variable for the references in order to match them with the reference attribute in the page elements.
Upon matching I can determine how many stars(*) to use depending on the position in the references list.

Comment: Read your favourite XSLT introduction on `xsl:key`.

Comment: Here's my favourite.... https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/02/06/key-lookups.html

Comment: There is a short, XSLT 1.0 (also working with XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 transformations / engines) solution. Keys have been there since XSLT 1.0 -- no need to enforce a higher version solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a key example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    expand-text="yes"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:key name="reference" match="references/reference" use="."/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="text-only-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" html-version="5"/>

  <xsl:template match="page[@referenceAttribute]">[<xsl:apply-templates select="key('reference', @referenceAttribute)" mode="asterisk"/>{@number}]</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="reference" mode="asterisk">
      <xsl:variable name="index" as="xs:integer">
          <xsl:number/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="(1 to $index)!'*'" separator=""/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="references"/>

  <xsl:template match="p">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>.NET XSLT Fiddle Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSSEuw/2

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a short (20 lines, 4 templates), XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vStars" select="'******************************'"/>

 <xsl:key name="kRefByVal" match="reference" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="page"><xsl:apply-templates select="@number|text()"/></xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@number">
    <xsl:value-of select=
     "concat(' [',
             substring($vStars,1,
                      count(key('kRefByVal', ../@referenceAttribute)/preceding-sibling::*) +1),
              .,
             '] ' )"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/></xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="references"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<a>
    <b>
        <references>
            <reference>reference 1</reference>
            <reference>reference 2</reference>
            <reference>reference 3</reference>
        </references>
    </b>
    <c>
        <d>
            <p>
            Sample text
                <page number="199" referenceAttribute="reference 2" /> Sample text 1
                <page number="17" referenceAttribute="reference 1" /> Sample text 2
                <page number="200" referenceAttribute="reference 2" /> Sample text 3
            </p>
        </d>
    </c>
</a>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
Sample text [**199] Sample text 1 [*17] Sample text 2 [**200] Sample text 3
```